# Peticion ajax envia datos POST pero no se reciben

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

Tengo este codigo que enviar datos de un formulario a un **script** externo

```
$(document).on("submit","#previewOc", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "assets/contentHtml/ocs/preview.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data:  new FormData(this),
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(data){
                         VentanaCentrada(\'assets/contentHtml/ocs/preview.php\',\'Orden\',\'\',\'1024\',\'768\',\'true\');
                        console.log(data);

                    }
                });
            });
```

Y en la consola me aparece que si se enviaron los datos **POST**, pero en mi **script**, al momento de hacer var_dump`($_POST)` aparece solo un array vacio, osea no se recibieron los datos `POST array()`

Que esta mal en mi codigo?, Gracias.

Comment: ¿Y qué hay dentro del `FormData(this)`?

Comment: `$("#previewOc").submit(function(e) {`  Es que lo habia intentado con este codigo el principio de la funcion, el this es el id del form, con eso le pasaba los datos, pero igual da la misma no los recibe

Comment: si lo envias via get te brinda rpta haciendo varDump del arr $_REQUEST ?

Comment: Si creas la variable: `var formData = new FormData(this);` y la imprimes en consola: `console.log(formData);` ¿qué muestra?

Comment: No, con **GET** nisiquiera los envia.

Comment: Haciendo la variable formData, no me imprime nada ni por GET ni por POST

Comment: ¿No te imprime nada en JS, o sea, en el código donde haces la llamada Ajax...? Si es así es un problema de la forma en que recoges los datos para pasarlos al servidor vía Ajax. ¿Estás seguro que `this` representa a tu formulario realmente?

Comment: Intenta modificando `url: "assets/contentHtml/ocs/preview.php",` por `url: "assets/contentHtml/ocs/preview.php?" + $(this).serialize()`, y elimina  `data:  new FormData(this),` y dinos que pasa.

Comment: `<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="previewOc">` en el form no tengo el action y en la funcion  `$("#previewOc").submit(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var formData = new FormData("#previewOc");
                    console.log(formData);`

No se si este haciendo algo mal

Comment: No @Einer... ¿por qué mejor no sugieres que cree una variable `formData=$(this).serialize();`  y que se la pase en el parámetro `data`. ?

Comment: @A.Cedano tambien puede intentarlo. Fue lo primero que me paso por la cabeza (>.<).

Comment: ¿Y, en este contexto, colocar `new FormData($(this))` es lo mismo que `new FormData(this)` ?

Comment: Parece claro que el problema es de contexto, intenta serializar los datos del form usando su id directamente, algo así: `var formData = $('#previewOc").serialize(); console.log(formData);` y en el Ajax: `.... method: "POST",
                    data:  formData, .... `  de paso, observa si ahora se imprimen los datos en la consola.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda, al final lo deje asi
`$("#previewOc").submit(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    formData = $("#previewOc").serialize();
                    console.log(formData);
                        success: function(data){
                            VentanaCentrada(\'assets/contentHtml/ocs/preview.php?\' + formData,\'Orden\',\'\',\'1024\',\'768\',\'true\');
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                });`

Ya recibe bien las variables

Comment: Creo que ya vi el error de tu código actual, `this` necesitaría el índice `0`, algo así: **`data:  new FormData(this[0])`** si realmente `this` representa a tu formulario, debería funcionar, sino, debería funcionar de este modo: `var frm=$('#previewOc"); var formData = new FormData(frm[0]);` y en la parte de Ajax: `data: formData`.  Si de ninguna manera funciona con `FormData` podría ser debido también a un problema de compatibilidad en tu navegador.

Comment: Es obvio que no estás enviando los datos, no es que no se reciban.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día... sobre tu código intenta por favor hacer las siguientes modificaciones:

```
var path = '../assets/contentHtml/ocs/preview.php?';

var valParam1 = $("#tuInput1").val();

var valParam2 = $("#tuInput2").val();

                $.ajax({    
                        type: "POST",  
                        url: path,
                        dataType: "html",
                        data: "param1="+valParam1+"&param2="+valParam2, 
                        success: function(data){                            
                        console.log(data);                      
                        },
                            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                            console.log("err");
                        }       
                });
```

Ahora bien si requieres llevarte todo tu formulario para el otro lado en tu ajax seria con una varible como la siguiente:

```
var tuForm = $("#idForm").serialize();

var valParam1 = tuForm;
```

y en tu ajax la remites de la siguiente manera:

```
data: "formulario="+valParam1,
```

En tu "script.php" revisa por favor con las siguientes lineas de código:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_REQUEST);
echo "</pre>";
```

Espero te sea de utilidad. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

podrias hacer algo como esto:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {

        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'post.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form fue enviado');
            }
          });

        });

      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input name="time" value="00:00:00.00"><br>
      <input name="date" value="0000-00-00"><br>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

para acceder a los datos podrias hacerlo asi:

```
$_POST['nombreInput']
```

espero haberte ayudado suerte !!

Comment: La url de la pregunta es : url: "assets/contentHtml/ocs/preview.php", esto es un ejemplo que no tiene relación con la pregunta. Te sugiero adecuarlo de acuerdo a la información del OP, revisar [answer], saludos.